# change text color of spinner's text (`android.r.id.text1') who is in sherlock actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image]

change text color of spinner who is created in sherlock action bar (Text View Id is) : `android.r.id.text1`

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: ` <style name="DropDownListView.My_actionbar_theme" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_my_actionbar_theme</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>`

Comment: @APOORVADOSHI, Try my below solution and also refer the link i provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way,

```
<style name="Custom.Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem" parent="Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem">
       <item name="android:textAppearance">
           @style/Custom.TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
       <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
       <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
   </style>

   <style name="Custom.TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"  parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
       <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
       <item name="android:shadowColor">#4ccfff</item>
       <item name="android:shadowDy">3</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
   </style>
```

For more information please visit this link,

http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-style-spinner-in-sherlock-actionbar/